# date subtraction in JavaScript react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, substring, subtraction

I have two strings representing a date a = 21-06-01.  and   b = 06/07/21.
Now I want to subtract 01 from a from 07 from b. means 07-01 = 06. please help

here is code but its saying cant find var Integer. and after removing Integer its returning NaN.

```
Integer.parseInt(b.substring(3,2)) - Integer.parseInt(a.substring(8,2))
```

Comment: *I have two numbers* - I think you really mean you have two strings representing a date.

Comment: yes yes.. two strings

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Take another example, a = 21-01-01 and b = 20-12-12, would you still want to substract 01 - 12 = - 11 ? Both strings are not even in the same format. So I would suggest to convert the strings to [date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) before doing any calculations

Comment: Drop the Integer namespace.  It's just `parseInt(b.substring(3,2)) - parseInt(a.substring(8,2))`.  But that's still not valid because neither of those `substring` calls return what you think they do.

Comment: Ingo Steinke. I have same format all time. my format of dates will never change